# How to add numbers in an integer

Tags: python, int, addition

I am a complete (GCSE) beginner in python.
I am trying to add the numbers in an integer. My variable FNT comes out as a different number every time (depending on what I have inputted earlier) and I then need the numbers to add themselves.    E.g. 
 FNT=19
 I now need the number to do this-
 1+9=10
       1+0=1                                                                                                                                                        The numbers need to keep adding themselves until they are a single digit but the number could be different every time. All help is greatly appreciated but, as I said I am a complete beginner and probably won't be able to understand anything too complicated, so would anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Could you please post a self-contained sample of your code illustrating the issue?

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly: do you want to add the digits of a number (which will be inputed by a user) and keep repeating the process until you have a result that is a single digit long?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two approaches: the mathematical way and the way that uses the fact that strings are iterables in python.

- The mathematical way uses modulo (`%`) and integral division (`//`) to decompose a number into digits:

  ```
  number = int(input('What number do you want to start with? '))

  while number > 9:
      decompose_helper, number = number, 0
      while decompose_helper: # != 0 is implied
          number += decompose_helper % 10
          decompose_helper = decompose_helper // 10

  print('Result is', number)
  ```

  You can improve this code using the [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) function:

  ```
  number = int(input('What number do you want to start with? '))

  while number > 9:
      decompose_helper, number = number, 0
      while decompose_helper: # != 0 is implied
          decompose_helper, remainder = divmod(decompose_helper, 10)
          number += remainder

  print('Result is', number)
  ```
- The iterable string way:

  ```
  number = input('What number do you want to start with? ')

  while len(number) > 1:
      number = str(sum(int(digit) for digit in number))

  print('Result is', number)
  ```

Neither of those code deal with input validation, so if your user enter something else than an integer, the code will crash. You might need to handle that.

---

I recommend using the mathematical way since it is faster. Timmings (removing `input` and `print`) are:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('math_way("4321234123541234")', setup='from __main__ import math_way', number=10000)
0.06196844787336886
>>> timeit.timeit('str_way("4321234123541234")', setup='from __main__ import str_way', number=10000)
0.10316650220192969
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To sum all the digits of a number, you can try a one-liner like this:

```
sum(int(chr) for chr in str(number))
```

You can apply that repeatedly until the result is less than 10:

```
res = number
while True:
  res = sum(int(chr) for chr in str(res))
  if res < 10:
    break
```

`res` now stores your result.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the most optimized, but it should do it:

```
def addThem(FNT):
    while FNT >= 10:
        FNT = sum([int(i) for i in list(str(FNT))])
    return FNT
```

EDIT:

if FNT = 19, list(str(FNT)) returns ['1', '9'].

The list comprehension [int(i) for i in list(str(FNT))] returns [1, 9] (notice these are now integers)

Comment: Try it with `FNT = 10`. It would return 10, which is not what we want.

Comment: You're right.  I must have had my head on backwards yesterday

Answer (score 0):

There are better ways of doing this but as a programming exercise this should give you some insight.

```
while digits>10:
t=0
for c in str(digits):
    t+=int(c)
digits=t
```

convert the input number into a string and iterate over the digits, repeat until the answer is single digit.

Answer (score 0):

This is done in java, but its still the same logic to be used  in python.

I made use of a `split`, to split the numbers, then i converted each of the splitted number to an integer, and added them up. I now used an `if statement` to check if the sum is greater than or equal to 10. if so, then i repeat the process again.

**This is the program**

```
    String num = "19"; //you can make use of any value here
    String array1[] = num.split("");
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= num.length(); i++) {
        sum = sum + Integer.parseInt(array1[i]); //converting each element to an integer then sum it up.
    }

    if (sum >= 10) {
        String newnum = sum + ""; //converting the sum to a string
        String newarray[] = newnum.split("");
        int newsum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i <= newnum.length(); i++) {
            newsum = newsum + Integer.parseInt(newarray[i]);
        }
        System.out.println( newsum);
    }else{
         System.out.println(num);
    }
```

**Output**

```
1
```

Comment: What about using `String num = '99999999999992';`? Your output is `11` instead of (presumably) `2`. And if `String num = "3";` there is no output at all.

Comment: Its true, can you tell me the reason why?

Comment: for the second one, you have the `println` inside the `if` and for the first one, you seem to be confusing `if` for a `while`. (but the logic is kinda flawed since you sort of duplicate your code.)

Comment: i have resolved d issue of it not printing out a single value. Remaining the 99992 part. Thanks a lot for your contribution